# MobileConnect message is not logging the send in SMSSendlog

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have created a SMSSendlog as per this knowledge article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387998&type=1

The objective is to be able to join the SMSSendlog with _smsMessageTracking DV and have custom attributes associated with send time data for downstream feeds/data analysis.

But the main issues is that the  MobileConnect messages are not being written to SMSSendlog even though the messages are successfully delivered to my handset. Have also queried the normal Sendlog which already existed (we use for email sends) and the messages aren't there either .

The details of the MobileConnect message below:

1. API triggered message in mobile connect
2. Being a API based message, there is no Keyword associated
3. Using subscriber and resubscribe as false in the sms/v1/messageContact/{id}/send
4. Passing custom attributes to log into the SMSSendlog

Payload below
{
"Subscribers": [
{
"MobileNumber": "61418xxxxxxx",
"SubscriberKey": "xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com",
"Attributes":{
"SMS_Line1":"Received funds",
"SMS_Line2":"{{$guid}}",
"CustomAttr1": "{{$guid}}"
}
}
],
"Subscribe": "false",
"Resubscribe": "false",
"Override": "false"
}

Is there any global or message level setting in Mobile connect to 'Retain Sendlog data' similar to Email activity? Do the messages need to be triggered from a Journey?

Will also raise a support case but hoping someone in this forum may be able to help.

Cheers
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised a case with support who made a 'backend' change (that could only be done by support). The SMS sends are now being logged. This was the detail provided:

*There is a business rule called "send logging" that needs to be enabled to use the send log. There are two fields in it, value and quality. To use the SMS send log, the value should be 1 and quality should be _AUTO.
In your case, the quality was blank and I just set it to _AUTO. It is just a minor setup. Also, this can only be done by the support.*